# Connecting Thunderbolt 1 iMac to Thunderbolt 4 M2 Mini in Target Disk Mode

Tags: thunderbolt, target-disk-mode

I need to get some data off of a 2013 iMac whose graphics adapter has failed. I can boot into single user mode but no other mode. I want to try to start it in Target Disk Mode.

I can't find a Thunderbolt 1 - Thunderbolt 4 adapter. Does such a thing exist? Would a Thunderbolt 2 - Thunderbolt 3 adapter work to connect to the M2 Mini? Or, to a Thunderbolt 3 MacBook Air?

Comment: Thunderbolt is backward compatible. The TB3 to TB2 adapter should do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a [Thunderbolt 2 cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD861LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-20-m) and a [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter).

You might want to look at "[Permissions for file transfer over target disk mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354169/permissions-for-file-transfer-over-target-disk-mode)" for insight on permissions and a command line method for transferring files.